# Clear all form element after submit form with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I am trying to clear all form element after submitting form but it clear only input box.but i have also check box to clear.I have used below code to clear form element.

```
jQuery('#cadandrivit').find(':input').each(function() {
                    switch(this.type){
                    case 'text':
                    jQuery(this).val('');
                    break;
                    case 'checkbox':
                    this.checked = false;
                    }
                    });
```

Please help how to unchecked all checkbox after submitting form.any short method for this kind of work? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

After ajax call getting successful message apply this code

```
$("#form_id").trigger("reset");
```

**[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/reset-selector/)**

Answer (score 0):

In case of check boxes or radio buttons remove the `checked` attribute like below

```
$(this).removeAttr("checked");
```

This will fix your issue.